# Hung program on a non-blocking socket

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, unix

At inconsistent intervals of time, I've seen one particular program becoming hung up lately (that is, halting execution but not crashing and not spinning the CPU). When termination with core dumps is forced, it's consistently stuck on this line:

```
int new_socket = accept4(listen_socket,NULL,NULL,SOCK_NONBLOCK);
```

Since this is a non-blocking accept, how can the program hang up there? It doesn't appear as if operating conditions change dramatically between functional and halted execution.

I am no network programming expert, so please let me know what other source (if any) would provide context for tracking this down.

EDIT: This software is running on and compiled with the following

```
$ uname -a
Linux phoenix 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
```

Comment: Which language is this in, C or C++?

Comment: It's very C-style C++, but it's compiled with g++, so that's what it is. I was broad with the tags because I figured sockets was... well, broad. =)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It's worth nothing the preferred norm afaik here is to only use a single "language tag" excepting questions specifically about language compatibility. Still, shall leave it up to you.

Comment: That's a good point. Details amended. Though, it seems that @alk has offered an answer anyway. Time to test...

Answer (score 3):

The option `SOCK_NONBLOCK` does not refer to the listening socket (the one passed to `accept4()`), but to the one getting created on acceptance of a connection.

Verbatim from [`man accept4`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> **SOCK_NONBLOCK**   Set the **O_NONBLOCK** file status flag on the new open file description.